# empty generic type when creating an object

Tags: java

Recently, I saw the following constructor call:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
```

I was surprised that one can call the constructor of the generic class `HashSet` with empty parentheses `<` and `>`. What does this mean?

Comment: Read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already declared what type of value (String in this case) the Set will hold, repeating it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you. So `new HashSet<>()` is just a shortcut writing for `new HashSet<String>()`?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood I think it shouldn't be considered a shortcut, because repeating the generic type in the `new` is completely pointless, so there is no need for shortcuts to get to that. It would be like saying that `1 + 1` is a shortcut for `1 + 1 + 0`. Eclipse has a warning when you do that: `Redundant specification of type arguments <String>`.

Answer (score 1):

this is diamond syntax, introduced since java7

reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/java-7-do-we-really-need